# How can I drop all but a few whitelisted metrics in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to drop all but a few whitelisted metrics in prometheus. I can persist them selectively with something like this:

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: (?i)(metric1|metric2|metric3)
    action: keep
```

However I want to drop all of the other, non-matching metrics. Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `keep` action drops everything that doesn't match, so that single action is enough to do what you want.

Comment: There were `relabel_configs` as well, so I guess those were persisting the other metrics. After removing those it works, thank you.

Comment: `relabel_configs` affect what targets are scraped, not what is returned from each scrape so that shouldn't have made a difference.